# My query in a stored procedure takes longer to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a script for the updating of my database

My query in a stored procedure takes longer to execute than the query in temporary table

Temporary table : 2 min

Query in a stored procedure = 12 min

**Temporary table**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS csii;
     create table csii
     SELECT 
         csii_id,
         csii_fk_cc,
         csii_s, csi_p, 
         csi_c_a,
         csi_o_p,
         csi_shi_c,
         csi_xc_s,
         csi_wei,
         csi_fk_c_at,
         csi_sta
     FROM
           cs
    WHERE 
          csii.sta = 'a';
```

**stored procedure**

```
     DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetAllProducts;
     SELECT * FROM csii;
     DELIMITER |

      CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts ()
      BEGIN
          DECLARE csii_id INT;
          DECLARE csii_fk_cc INT;
          DECLARE csii_s VARCHAR(255);
          DECLARE csi_p DECIMAL;
          DECLARE csi_c_a DATE;
          DECLARE csi_o_p DECIMAL;
          DECLARE csi_shi_c DECIMAL;
          DECLARE csi_xc_s VARCHAR(20);
          DECLARE csi_wei VARCHAR(20);
          DECLARE csi_fk_c_at INT;
         DECLARE csi_sta enum('a','i','d');

     SELECT 
        id, fk_cc, s, p, c_a, o_p, shi_c, xc_s, wei, fk_c_at, sta
     INTO 
        csii_id, csii_fk_cc, csii_s, csi_p, csi_c_a, csi_o_p, csi_shi_c,
         csi_xc_s, csi_wei, csi_fk_c_at, csi_sta
 FROM 
        csii
 WHERE 
        csi_sta = sta AND csi_sta = 'a';

END|
DELIMITER ;
```

I need your help please.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are using two different queries. What is your question?

Comment: `create table csii` and then by selecting from same table ? did not quite understand this part.

Comment: Indeed you should explain what you need really is....

Comment: I want to update this table in script every day I do the selection of these fields with the condition stat = a
It's a bit the same request on temprory table and stored procedure.

Comment: Abhik Chakraborty,I changed the fields and forgot to change the table that is it .

Comment: CrazyMenConnected what i want to do is create a script which help me to update my database every day when i execute it. I start with my first table and i test it with two ways : temprory table and stored procedure. temprory table takes 2 minutes and stored procedures takes 12 minutes

Comment: you are asking about performance of the queries ?

Comment: I want to know if i am in the right direction and if it is normal that the query in the  stored procedure is very slow

Comment: yes because i have a script with temporary tables but it takes a lot of time to update my database i want to use stored procedure for optimization queries and reduce the execution time

Comment: Moudiz yes that what i want.